# Single star RatingBar

Tags: android

I'm trying to display a RatingBar View that is only capable of showing a one star rating, or no stars.  This seems so trivial...

My ratingbar is defined like so:

My view implements OnRatingBarChangeListener and OnTouchListener

My OnRatingBarChange handler has no code.
My OnTouch handler looks like so:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
{
    if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
    {
        if(this.mRating.getRating() == 0)
        {
            this.mRating.setRating(1);
        }
        else
        {
            this.mRating.setRating(0);
        }
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

No matter what, the onTouch event does not succeed at setting the rating back to zero.  This seems way too trivial.  What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 14):

Consider using `ToggleButton` and `btn_star` stock drawable instead. Here's example:

```
    <ToggleButton
        android:button="@android:drawable/btn_star"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:textOn=""
        android:textOff=""
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Answer (score 0):

The RatingBar is extended from the SeekBar and the listener actually expects a slide action. Thus the RB can't be set to 0 (or not for this purpose) when there is only one star. The proper widget to use for this type of functionality (no surprise here) is the ToggleButton.

I had the same problem, trying to use a single star RatingBar as a favourite button. But the ToggleButton is exactly what you need for this type of thing.

This is what I implemented for the ToggleButton. (The `_favourited` bool was specifically used for something in my code, I can't remember now)

```
favourite_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
    if (!_favourited) {
      // Do stuff                  
      _favourited = true;
    } else {
      // Do stuff                 
      _favourited = false;
    }
}});
```